# How to multiply a pandas df column with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I want to mutiply the column prix in pandas df * 1000 but it returns an expected value and I didn't know why it works like that.
for exemple i want to return 57 to 257000 but it turns it like this 5757575757575757575757575757575757575757575757

I used this code

```
 c['prix'] = c['prix'].apply(lambda x: x * 1000 if len(str(x)) == 2 else x)
```

How to fix it please

Comment: You have strings, convert to integer first

Comment: @mozway i added this code too and it didnt work " c['Année'] = c['Année'].astype(int) "

Comment: Check my answer below and make sure to use the correct columns ("année" != "prix")

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to have integers and use vectorial code:

```
# convert strings to numeric
c['prix'] = pd.to_numeric(c['prix'], errors='coerce')

# multiply numbers with 2 digits by 1000
c.loc[c['prix'].between(10, 99), 'prix'] *= 1000
```